# Cell values looks different to others on SharePoint

Tags: web-part, excel, formatting

I have an excel sheet stored on SharePoint. It has a table in it. The cells of this table get a value based on a formula I run on another PIVOT table.

The formula returns the value as either **P** or **Blank**

I wanted the P to appear as a tick mark so I have changed the format of cells to Windings 2.

This table with cells formatted in Windings 2 is being projected as a webapp on another SharePoint page.

I can see the P's appear as a tick mark on the SharePoint page but others cannot.

Is this because of the access people have on the Excel sheet?